# Is it possible for a chrome extention popup to be part of the page?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension but when I use the "default_popup" I can see that it only allows a max height and width, and it is appearing inline over the content of the website. Is it possible to reduce the main browser page to 80% and have 20% of the visible screen for the extension?

Is there another term I can use instead of "default_popup" in "browser_action" to achieve this?

Comment: Not with browser_action because it's a separate window. You can insert a DOM element (also an iframe pointing to your html file exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)) and style it and the page accordingly. There's no API to do exactly what you want in Chrome, only in Opera and Firefox you can use their own Sidebar API.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with an extension recently. I wanted content to be inserted at the top of the browser window and I wanted that content to extend to 100% of the width content window. Since a popup is limited in both width and height, I went with the approach of creating the element to be inserted (for me that was a wrapper div with some content and some buttons) and then appending each of these elements to the body of the page. For example:

```
let body = document.body;
let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'kty208wrapper')

let header = document.createElement('h1')
    header.setAttribute('id', 'kty208header')

// create buttons for increasing/decreasing font size
let btnBigger = document.createElement('button')
btnBigger.innerHTML = "+"
let btnSmaller = document.createElement('button')
btnSmaller.innerHTML = "–"

// add wrapper, header, and bigger/smaller buttons to page
body.insertBefore(wrapper, body.firstChild);
wrapper.appendChild(header)
wrapper.appendChild(btnBigger)
wrapper.appendChild(btnSmaller)
```

With the wrapper div I used body.insertBefore to insert the content before the start of the body content (so that my wrapper div would show at the very top of the page).

Then I appended the header and buttons to the wrapper div.

Then I was able to write my functions to reference the inserted html elements like so:

```
let currentSize = 60;

btnBigger.onclick = function() { 
   currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize) + 5 + 'px';
   bigURL.style.fontSize = currentSize 
   bigURL.style.lineHeight = currentSize
}
```

Since I wanted this code to be run when a user clicked the extension icon (and not on page load) I created a background script called background.js and listened for the onClicked event. One a user clicked the icon I executed the code above, which was stored in a separate file called content.js. I had to have separate scripts because background scripts don't have access to modify the dom.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   // when a user clicks the extension icon, execute content.js
   // content.js has access to the current tab's DOM while
   // background.js doesn't.
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
});
```

I hope this helps!